# Heroku websocket to websocket communication

Tags: python, flask, heroku, websocket, redis

I'm trying to implement an invite system for my game using Heroku and websockets. I have tried the [official Heroku example](https://github.com/heroku-examples/python-websockets-chat/blob/master/chat.py) but it doesn't work.

Here is the basic app:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask-sock import Sock

app = Flask(__name__)
sock = Sock(app)

messages = []

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Nothing here..."

@sock.route("/submit")
def inbox(ws):
    while True:
        msg = ws.receive()
        ws.send("Message received.")
        messages.append(msg)

@sock.route("/receive")
def outbox(ws):
    while True:
        for msg in messages:
            ws.send(msg)
```

Even something as simple as that doesn't work, and from the tests I've run it seems like it's because each websocket connection is getting it's own instance of `messages`, and it seems like in the Heroku example it's the same deal with `self.clients`.

Here's my requirements.txt:

```
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.5
Flask==2.2.2
flask-sock==0.5.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
h11==0.13.0
importlib-metadata==4.12.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
passlib==1.7.4
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
simple-websocket==0.8.0
Werkzeug==2.2.2
wsproto==1.1.0
zipp==3.8.1
requests==2.26.0
redis==4.3.4
gevent==21.12.0
```

and my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn app:app --timeout 200
```

and my runtime.txt:

```
python-3.9.6
```

What I want is essentially a way to send data from one websocket to another without having to query a database constantly. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have imported `flask_sock` package not `flask_socket` package.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).